# New tables created in web2py not seen when running in Google app Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I have created an app using web2py and have declared certain new table in it using the syntax
db.define_table() but the tables created are not visible when I run the app in Google App Engine even on my local server. The tables that web2py creates by itself like auth_user and others in auth are available.

What am I missing here?
I have declared the new table in db.py in my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

App Engine datastore doesn't really have tables. That said, if web2py is able to make use of the datastore (I'm not familiar with it), then Kinds (a bit like tables) will only show up in the admin-console (/_ah/admin locally) once an entity has been created (i.e. tables only show up once one row has been inserted, you'll never see empty tables).